# android:headerDividersEnabled isn't working

Tags: android, listview, header, divider

I want to have a divider at the top of a `ListView` (which is placed in `RelativeLayout`), but when I try to use this, I get only the bottom divider:

```
<ListView
        android:id="@+id/last_contacts_picked_list"
        android:headerDividersEnabled="true"
        android:footerDividersEnabled="true"
        android:paddingTop="50dp"
        android:dividerHeight="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
        android:divider="@android:drawable/divider_horizontal_textfield"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_above="..."
        android:layout_alignLeft="..."
        android:layout_alignRight="..."
        android:layout_below="..."
         />
```

I've got something like this:

http://i051.radikal.ru/1211/4f/a408db5e717f.png

Why doesn't it have the header divider too?

Comment: post the code for adding the headers

Answer (score 12, accepted):

That is not what [android:headerDividersEnabled](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html#attr_android%3aheaderDividersEnabled) is supposed to do. It means that if you are adding a list header whether that header needs to be separated by a divider or not.

For your problem simply use a linearlayout with ImageView having the divider as source followed by ListView. Hope this helps.